# how to offset specific unit of length from a map area(polygon) with latitude and longitude in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, gps, gis, polygon, offset

I have a set of latitude and longitude array like [ [ lat1, lon1 ],[ lat2, lon2 ],[ lat3, lon3 ] ] which forms a area(polygon), I would like to offset outward this geography area(polygon) by specific unit of length(like 1 meter or 1.5 meter).

Then I will finally get new set of array [ [newlat1,newlon1], [newlat2,newlon2], [newlat3,newlon3] ]

the code in JavaScripit below:

```
let oldLocation = [ [25.049956, 121.568885], [25.049999, 121.568941], [25.049999, 121.568885] ]

function offetGeoArea(area, offsetDistance)={
  
  //the  offset algorithm
  
  return newLocation
}
```

the offset diagram below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2byUO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't as simple as you've made it sound, to move a point by a given distance you need to account for it's latitude in particular. Moving 1 degree to the West is a hugely different distance at the equator than it is near the poles.

That said there are frameworks like CesiumJS that have the things you need to do this. CesiumJS is a little heavy if you're trying to keep it light javascript. Whatever mapping technology you have underneath probably has similar features to calculate a point.

So one vote for https://cesiumjs.org

Comment: Also I just re-read your question and saw the word "outward" - do you want to keep the same shape in the same place and just make it grow? In which case you might be looking to lerp from a specified point using something like a CesiumJS Cartesian2